# Navigation bar with Search bar iPad Monotouch

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, searchbar

I want to have a page like this:

[image]

It is the map page of the iPad map. As you can see it has a location search bar on the top.

Is it possible to have a search bar like this image on the top when the screen have navigation bar on his top?

EDIT:
More than implementing this, it is important that using a search bar on a navigation bar was not wrong with apples guide line. please help also about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not agains iphone quide line. my application with this search bar approved.

The below code will add uisearch bar to your navigation bar:

```
LocationSearchBar = new UISearchBar (new RectangleF (0,0,250,44));
            UIBarButtonItem searchButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem (LocationSearchBar );
this .NavigationItem .RightBarButtonItem =searchButtonItem;
```